# Call mysql link on each function or pass the link through them?

Tags: php, performance, function, mysqli

I do not know the best way, for performance, schema to call mysql link.

Which is better:
Do I call my MySQL link on each function, or call it just one time, and then pass the link through the functions?

For example,

Require through each function:

```php
function one(){
  require('mysql.php');
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}

function two(){
  require('mysql.php');
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}

function three(){
  require('mysql.php');
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
```

Or require one time and then pass the link to the functions:

```php
require('mysql.php');

function one($link){
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}

function two($link){
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}

function three($link){
  $query = 'SELECt * FROM table';
  $sql   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
```

I want know which of these is the best way to gain performance (even if was just a little) and to avoid to overcharging my database because all these functions will be called on in sequence.

I'm not using PDO.
And the question marked as the duplicate has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Sorry Alon, but the other question don't fully my doubt. I'm not using PDO and not have nothing to do with my doubt.

Comment: ... yeah that was a poor duplicate choice, and the advice over there is harmful.

Comment: Really depends on what's in `mysql.php` but I would strongly recommend the second approach anyway

Comment: Hi @Phil, Could you put some details about performance or security reasons why the second approach is better?

Comment: Not without knowing what's in mysql.php, no

Comment: it's a simple _connect

```php
$connect_sql = mysqli_connect('p:'.$server_sql, $login_sql, $senha_sql,$dados_sql);
mysqli_set_charset($connect_sql,"utf8");
$erro_sql = mysqli_error($connect_sql);

if(!$connect_sql){
 echo $erro_sql;
}
```